# Calculating the $p$-value with Wilks' Theorem

Tags: particle-physics, statistics

I am stuck at understanding the following: According to Wilks' Theorem, the test-statistic $$q_0 = -2\cdot \ln\frac{\mathcal L\left( S = 0\right)}{\mathcal L\left( \hat{S}\right)}$$ follows a $\chi^{2}$-distribution with $1$ d. o. f. (I am aware that there is also a more general form of this theorem, but let's stick to the simplified version for now).

In a lecture, it was said that we can thus compute the $p$-values from the Gaussian quantiles as follows:

$$p_{0} = 1 - \Phi\left( \sqrt{q_0}\right)$$

Could anybody elaborate on this conclusion, please, particularly why Wilks' Theorem plays a role here?

Comment: Would Math.SE be a better home for this question?

Comment: This should be posted here: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: This can be physics, just give some context (e.g., searches for new particles at LHC).  I suggest to see https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1727, in particular Sec. 3.5

Comment: Exactly, the context is search for the Higgs boson at the LHC and BSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if we have a test statistic $x$ with a known CDF $C(x_{\rm thresh})=P(x\leq x_{\rm thresh})$ under the null hypothesis, then the (one-sided) $p$-value for measuring $x=x_0$ or larger assuming the null hypothesis is $p=P(x\geq x_0)=1-P(x\leq x_0)=1-C(x_0)$.

We can relate this to the PDF $f(x)$ (assuming the null hypothesis, in your case $S=0$) as follows. The CDF is
\begin{equation}
C(x_0) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_0} f(x) dx
\end{equation}
Assuming $f(x)$ is normalized so $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx f(x) = 1$, then the CDF is related to the $p$-value by
\begin{equation}
p = \int_{x_0}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1 - \int_{-\infty}^{x_0} f(x) dx = 1-C(x_0)
\end{equation}
as stated above.

Since $q$ is drawn from a $\chi^2$ distribution with 1 dof, then $\sqrt{q}$ is drawn from a Gaussian distribution. Assuming $\Phi(x)$ is the CDF for a zero mean, unit variance Gaussian random variable, then $1-\Phi(\sqrt{q_0})$ would give you the $p$-value for measuring $q$ to be as large or larger than $q_0$.

I think Wilk's theorem is only used to say that the log likelihood ratio approaches the $\chi^2$ distribution asymptotically.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure: (i) Is $1-\Phi\left( \sqrt{q_{0}} \right)$ the $p$-value for measuring $q$ or $\sqrt{q}$ then? (ii) Okay, the way I see it, we know that Wilk's Theorem holds, thus we have a $\chi^{2}$-distribution for $q$, and hence a Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and st.dev. $1$ for $\sqrt{q}$?

Comment: @MathIsFun (i) It won't matter. The $p$ value for measuring $q$ to be larger than $q_0$ is the same as the $p$ value for measuring $\sqrt{q}$ to be larger than $\sqrt{q_0}$. I can try to justify this more if you want but if you think about, it should hopefully make sense intuitively that it can't matter if you use $q_0$ or $\sqrt{q_0}$. (ii) Exactly. There are two subtleties that I'm not sure of but presumably can be resolved in your case. 1 is that Wilk's Theorem holds for asymptotic distributions, and I don't see what is "large" here. 2 is that I don't know what sign to take for $\sqrt{q}$.

Comment: (ii) Concerning the first point you brought up: In a set of lectures I listened to, it was said that Wilk's Theorem holds for $n\to \infty$, so basically when we can apply the central-limit theorem and assume that $\mathcal L\left( \hat{S}\right)$ follows a Gaussian. It was said that in practice, for event counts of $\mathcal O\left( 5\right)$ this would be applicable. :) 

(i) I would appreciate a brief edit of your post. What I have until now: $$p_{0} = \int_{q_{obs}}^{\infty}f(q_{0} \vert S = 0)dq_{0}, $$ but I am stuck from here. What I just wrote down is the "definition" ...

Comment: ... of $p_{0}$, so basically the fraction of outcomes that are at least as extreme (signal-like) as the data, under the hypothesis that $H_{0}$ is true (so we bascically have no signal present, $S = 0$). $f$ should be the PDF of the test-statistic $q_{0}$.

Comment: @MathIsFun (i) I added a paragraph relating the CDF, p value, and PDF. (ii) I guess I would have thought that, say, $n=5$ would have corresponded to a $\chi^2$ distribution with 5 dof. I'm not saying there is a problem with the lectures, I just don't quite see (given the information in the question) what asymptotic limit is being taken.